# Problems with npm install on angular application

Tags: angular, npm, sass, angular-material

So I've this project where I need to work on an older version of angular, it is the version 12.0, I want to update it, but whenever I try to do it so it never goes foward.

First off all I've tryed to install the npm and this error appears

[image]

I can force install it, but it always comes with errors, I've audit it fixed and ok, the project runs.

The point is, I wanted to update the angular version to the newer one, change the css files to scss and add material design to it, the project is currently using bootstrap.
Anyways, whenever I try to change the files to css it returns me an error, if i try to change versions it returns erros.

The project it's running firebase with it, does it interfere with angular in anyway?
Shoulnd't i by able to install npm without any problems?

If i try to update angular without installing npm it returns this...

[image]

Is there any reason why this is happening? Can someone help me with this?
Even if i force install the npm i can't update angular anyways

this error appears

[image]

and i'm using it's doc to do it so

https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-13.0

I've searched everywhere and coulnd't find a reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the issue comes from one of your package.

Like in the first image `angularx-social-login@4.0.1`, this package is [only compatible with Angular 12](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login), but you are updating to Angular 13.

So the solution is read the error message, see what package is yelling, check again the documentation to see whether it supports new version of Angular.

Comment: Yes, i noticed that, but shoulnd't i be at least able to install npm without forcing it? That's whats bothering me.

I was talking with my supervisor and he said that i't had something to do with firebase, but he was in such a hurry that I doesn't seem "right"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean at all. You said you "noticed" but you still asking about "without forcing"? The reason is real simple: major version will change some code, so it isn't sure whether it's gonna work, that's why the warning and that's why you have to force it, when you force it, you accept the risk that your package will stop working due to incompatible

Comment: Yeah, my bad there.
I have forced the npm install and for some reason I can't use my admins to login in my aplication, nothing on my database is usefull.

I know that forcing may result in some errors, but shouldn't i be able to install npm without problems? Why is this happening? Thats my issue, because i know that forcing things may result in errors, but how i'm supposed to use, modify this app if I can't even open it without breaking it?

Comment: So you know "force" = "maybe stop working" => Now your app stops working. So first thing first, revert all the changes so that the app is back to normal. From there, to upgrade to newer version of angular without any problem, you should first update your dependencies, take the social-login as an example, you can't update because that package isn't compatible with angular 13, so update the package first. Do that for each of every package in your app that is not compatible with newer version of angular, then you can upgrade angular.

Comment: Thanks man, apperently angularx-social-login@4.0.1 only works till angular 12.0 so i'm going to remove it from the app and use Firebase to make the authentications with google and facebook

Comment: Let's altogether hope that it's the only package that incompatible with new angular. Good luck.

Comment: Well it wasn't lol. But I decided to do some heavy work. I made a new project updated and all, then i removed all the stuff that i dind't need and installed everything that i wanted. Now it's working. I know that it was kind of dumb to do it like this, but when i realized that i needed to go installing one by one, veryfing wich was needed to what i thought it would be faster this way